# Question on the derivative of a function $f:D(\subseteq\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> **Definition**
>
> Let $f:D(\subseteq \mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in D$. Then we say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if, $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$exists and we write, $$f'(a)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$if for all $a\in D$ the limit exists then we say that the function $f$ is differentiable on $D$.

Today in class when our professor stated the above definition one of my batchmate put forward the following question,

> How can we say that the function $f'$ is unique? What if we put forward the definition as follows,
>
> > **Alternative Definition**
> >
> > Let $f:D(\subseteq \mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in D$. Then we say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if, $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$exists. We say that the function $f$ is differentiable on $D$ if for all $a\in D$ there exist a function $g$ such that $a\in \text{dom}\ g$ and $$g(a)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
>
> Now it may be noted that we simply claim the existence of a function $g$. Unless we prove uniqueness we cannot label it by a unique symbol $f'$.

To this question I put forward the following answer,

> Consider the following mapping for all $a\in D$ where the limit exists, $$\mathscr{\theta}(a)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$What we simply do is to take $\theta=f'$.

Is there any flaw in my argument? If there is, how can I modify my argument (if it can be modified at all)? Is there any other way to prove the uniqueness of $f'$?

Comment: Have you seen $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs?

Comment: @AlexS: Not for derivative related problems. Only for continuous functions, limits and sequences.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that if a limit in the reals exists, that it is unique. This is done by employing the $\varepsilon-\delta$ formalism you may have seen. The formal definition of a limit is $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=L$$ exists if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=S$. We would like to show that $L=S$. Choose $\varepsilon<|L-S|/2$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ and $|f(x)-S|<\varepsilon$. But this cannot work because $\varepsilon<|L-S|/2$, unless $L=S$. Thus, limits are unique, even if they represent derivatives.

Comment: It's not the uniqueness of the limit of which I am talking about. It's the uniqueness of the **function**. Note that we cant define the mapping $\theta$ in the way I have defined since the limit is unique.

Comment: But you have defined the value of the function $\theta $ at each point by a limit. Since $f'$ is given by the same limit, these must be equal at each point. If two functions take the same value at each point, they are equal.